# Java Comparison issue - Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, comparator

I am trying to do a sorting of some number. I am getting a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!" Exception when I execute the following code.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class ComparatorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> ll = List.of("1.A", "1.A.1", "10.A", "10.A.1", "10.A.2", "10.A.3", "12.A", "12.A.1", "12.A.2",
                "12.A.4", "12.A.6", "1A.2", "2.A.1", "2.A.1.b", "2.A.1.b.1", "2.A.1.b.2", "2.A.1.b.3", "20.A.1",
                "20.A.1.a", "20.A.1.b", "20.A.1.b.1", "20.A.1.b.2", "3.A.1", "3.A.1.a", "3.A.1.a.1", "3.A.1.a.2",
                "3.A.1.a.3", "3.A.1.a.4", "3.A.1.b", "3.A.10", "6.A.1", "9.A.1");
        
        ArrayList<String> l2 = new ArrayList<>(ll);
        Collections.sort(l2, (obj1, obj2) -> {
            try {
                String[] prodClass1 = obj1.split("\\.");
                String[] prodClass2 = obj2.split("\\.");
                for (int i = 0; (i < prodClass1.length) && (i < prodClass2.length); i++) {
                    if (!prodClass1[i].equals(prodClass2[i])) {
                        if (StringUtils.isNumeric(prodClass1[i]) && StringUtils.isNumeric(prodClass2[i])) {
                            return Integer.valueOf(prodClass1[i]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(prodClass2[i]));
                        } else {
                            return prodClass1[i].compareToIgnoreCase(prodClass2[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return obj1.compareToIgnoreCase(obj2);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return obj1.compareToIgnoreCase(obj2);
            }
        });
        System.out.println(l2);
    }
    
}
```

Interstingly if I remove any 1 element form the list ll, the code works just fine.

I think this has to do something related to equals() and compare() method. But can someone pinpoint the whats wrong here.

If I add one extra condition in the custom comparator it works. Why it is like this? Can anyone pinpoint the issue.

Modified code

```
Collections.sort(l2, (obj1, obj2) -> {
            try {
                String[] prodClass1 = obj1.split("\\.");
                String[] prodClass2 = obj2.split("\\.");
                for (int i = 0; (i < prodClass1.length) && (i < prodClass2.length); i++) {
                    if (!prodClass1[i].equals(prodClass2[i])) {
                        if (StringUtils.isNumeric(prodClass1[i]) && StringUtils.isNumeric(prodClass2[i])) {
                            return Integer.valueOf(prodClass1[i]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(prodClass2[i]));
                        } else if (StringUtils.isNumeric(prodClass1[i]) || StringUtils.isNumeric(prodClass2[i])) {
                            return StringUtils.isNumeric(prodClass1[i]) ? -1 : 1;
                        } else {
                            return prodClass1[i].compareToIgnoreCase(prodClass2[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return obj1.compareToIgnoreCase(obj2);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return obj1.compareToIgnoreCase(obj2);
            }
        });
```

The below is the output when I execute the code after adding some logs:

```
prodClass1: [3, A, 1, a, 1] Comparing with prodClass2: [2, A, 1, b, 3]
prodClass1: [2, A, 1, b, 3] Comparing with prodClass2: [3, A, 1, a]
prodClass1: [2, A, 1, b, 3] Comparing with prodClass2: [3, A, 1]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:903)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:520)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(TimSort.java:461)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:254)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1515)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1750)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:179)
    at core.ComparatorTest.main(ComparatorTest.java:30)
```

Comment: I think it would be much easier to diagnose what's going on if you change the code to log the two inputs and the result each time a comparison is made. That log should make it clearer. I *suspect* there'll be some x, y, z for which x < y, y < z but x >z.

Comment: This is what I got after adding debugs: 

prodClass1: [3, A, 1, a, 1] Comparing with prodClass2: [2, A, 1, b, 3]
prodClass1: [2, A, 1, b, 3] Comparing with prodClass2: [3, A, 1, a]
prodClass1: [2, A, 1, b, 3] Comparing with prodClass2: [3, A, 1]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
 at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:903)
 at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:520)

Comment: Please put that in the question as a list. It's really hard to read with it all just inline. And you need to include the *result* - just seeing what it's comparing doesn't help.

Comment: Note in the loop that `!prodClass1[i].equals(prodClass2[i])` isn't consistent with the non-numeric case return `prodClass1[i].compareToIgnoreCase(prodClass2[i])`. Consider using `prodClass1[i].equalsIgnoreCase(prodClass2[i])` for the first check.

Comment: Also, in the case that the arrays have different lengths, you should be returning a value based on which of the arrays is longer (e.g. `return Integer.compare(prodClass1.length, prodClass2.length)`, rather than using lexicographic string comparison.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for feedback, is there any particular reason for mentioning that I should return based on which array is longer?

Comment: @jos.mathew because not doing so will result in more `a<b, b<c, a>c` violations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you violate the contract, then `sort` can do one of two things, **and the spec does not guarantee either behaviour**:

- The output of sort is utterly gobbledygook.
- You get that exception.

Hence, if you do *not* get that exception, that *does not* imply your code is fine. Absence of exception is not proof of absence of bugs. Hence, "If I remove an element this exception goes away" is meaningless. The key problem here is the 1A entry.

You can zoom in on just `"10.A", "1A.2", "2.A.1"`.

- As per your code, 10.A is less than 1A.2, because string ordering is used on the first component, and `"10".compareTo("1A")` is negative - `"10"` is considered as coming before `"1A"`.
- As per your code, 1A.2 is less than 2.A.1, because string ordering is used on the first component, and `"1A".compareTo("2")` is negative - `"1A"` is considered as coming before `"2"`.

So far, so obvious, right? However..

- As per your code, 10.A is **not** less than 2.A.1, because the integer ordering is used on the first component (as they are both numeric), and 10 is *after* 2.

Hence, we have the following scenario:

- A comes before B, and B comes before C...
- but A comes after C.

Which, obviously, is impossible.

The general contract of comparison methods involves:

- `a.equals(b)`? then `a.compareTo(b) == 0`.
- `a.compareTo(a) == 0`.
- `a.compareTo(b)` needs to be the opposite of `b.compareTo(a)`.
- `a.compareTo(b)` and `b.compareTo(c)` are the same direction? Then `a.compareTo(c)` must also be that direction (a is before b and b is before c? Then a must also be before c - same for 'after').

You've violated that last one. The second snippet fixes it by treating `1A` as being after `10`.

There are more ways in which your comparison code violates the rules, and, as you found out, violation of the rules doesn't guarantee exceptions. Your general approach of 'eh, fall back to string sorting' is a bad one. For example, you should not just fall back to that if one is 'longer' than the other (instead, the longer way needs to always win/lose from the shorter one).

Comment: There is a third possible outcome: sort produces the intended output for a particular input by chance. Which is the worst, when occurring during testing…